# Disable Trinidad's automatic addition of stylesheets

Tags: css, apache, trinidad

Does anyone knows how to completely disable skinning support in Apache Trinidad?

All I need from the solution is to skip sending trinidad-specific CSSes all together.

I'm trying to overcome some CSS issues arising from theirs styles (like the one adding 8px top margin on IE with the absolutely highest priority).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue for a while, try removing the `<tr:document>` tags from your pages, at least in our case that completly removed any additional styling that trinidad skinning tried to add.  Now there are other CSS additions that trinidad adds in it's very nature, and that I don't believe you can get rid of.

Comment: This removed some of the stylesheets but unfortunately not the ones messing with page margins.
Fortunately for me I no longer work with JSF (doing Grails now) so this is not my problem anymore (so to speak) :)

Comment: @Matthias That's good to hear, I'm looking forward to the day that I can move away from `trinidad`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the basic skin?  It might provide something pretty close to what you want.  After that, you can override and inhibit all the defaults.